# Can't start X session after updating packages

Tags: unity, updates, xorg

I have recently upgraded to 12.04 and all seems okay except **adobe flash plugin** doesn't work. But several days ago when I installed several update packages and rebooted, X session was unable to start and it automatically switches to console 1 for command line login.

What's frustrating is there's essentially no error messages when I click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to see what's going on with X session. There are a bunch of `[ok]`'s and the last line seems to be something like `starting x font server` and it just hang there.

The closest thing to an error is something like `stopping system V compatability (\*words I can't remember\*) ...  [ok]'`.

This is nearly the most frustrating experience I've ever had with Linux in the past 10 years. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling the graphics driver and remove `xorg.conf`:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Comment: Thanks. It turned out it was due to the graphic card driver. X started normally after uninstalling the graphic card driver.